# Classic ASP tick checkbox based on textbox value and checked against a database

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I am trying to get my head how to write a piece of code in Classic ASP and JQuery. I have a textbox with autocomplete where the user can select from a value in the database. Once the value in entered into the textbox, I want it to update a checkbox with the value true or false depending on what is in the database.

For example, say that the user enters the value 'John' in the textbox, I want it to go to the database, check if dbo.NotificationSettings.NotifyUser is true or false. Then I want it to automatically, tick a checkbox (notifyuser) depending on the database value.

This is the textbox

```
<input name="AssignedAgent" type="text" class="FormValues" id="AssignedAgent" />
```

This is the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="smsagent" id="smsagent" />
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind functionality to the onChange event of the input, and avoid posting back the whole form by using jQuery's [ajax](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/&ei=9j17UtbSCMjpswbg94CoCA&usg=AFQjCNF1ITsE5bJBc65MY4nqhZq7OkHZpg&sig2=UZd01I1jhPLZ9wLOBtAUYw&bvm=bv.56146854,d.Yms), like this:

```
$('#AssignedAgent').on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({

        //you need to process the data sent with a back-end script 
        //that returns json:
        url: '/some/path/to/process/input',

        //tell jquery-ajax that it will receive json data
        dataType: 'json',

        //grab the value of AssignedAgen and send it up as 
        //a name-value pair (javascript object):
        data: {
            AssignedAgent: $(this).val()
        },

        //process the results:
        success: function (response) {

            //check the box using some logic with the values returned:
            if (response.someField == 'some-value') {
                $('#smsagent').prop('checked', true);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

As mentioned in the comment, you need to have a handling script on the back-end that returns json. Here's an overview: HOW TO: [Use JSON with Ajax & Classic ASP](http://ko-lwin.blogspot.de/2011/01/how-to-use-json-with-ajax-classic-asp.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to use your code and combined that with your link to JSON, It is now working. Although I am trying to figure out how to disable the checkbox when the condition is not true.

I have put an else condition but doesn't seem to work.

    else {
      $('#smsagent').prop('checked', false); 
     }

Comment: Actually.. I just sorted it out. Turns out that I forgot to make the SQL check against the variable that I am passing. Thanks!!